# How do I migrate a Java webapp to Heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, jetty

I have an app that uses `Spring` and is run with Jetty.  I was hosting it on an Amazon EC2 instance but now I want to put it on Heroku. If found the following link but I don't know if it covers everything and since I'm new to Heroku and, to a lesser extent GIT, it seems overwhelming:

```
   http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/01/spring-onto-heroku.html
```

Does anyone have experience doing this and if so what is the first step?  I do have a test Java app running on `Heroku`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Heroku Dev Center should answer most of your questions:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java

In particular, the Spring MVC example article should help you get started:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/spring-mvc-hibernate